# Windows 8.1 Get current playing song

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

How is it possible in win8.1 to get the current playing song in the Music app, in order to use it to my win8.1 app?

I've tried using the `SystemMediaTransportControls.DisplayUpdater.MusicProperties.Title`, but it doens't seem to work.

Comment: Have you gotten anywhere with this, I could also use this. I've tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957181/retrieve-song-name-from-wmp-using-c-sharp but that's only good for windows media player

Comment: No, unfortunately, I haven't found a way to implement it.